# Does Webots simulator support closed-loop kinematic chains?

Tags: ros, webots

Short version is the post title.

Long explanation here.

Recently, I've been working on a rover project, the suspension mechanism for which is [rocker-bogie mechanism with a differential bar (not a gearbox)](https://alicesastroinfo.com/2012/07/mars-rover-rocker-bogie-differential/) .

I have been working on the simulation task using Gazebo but the problem is [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) does not support closed-loop kinematic chains and the rocker-bogie suspension mechanism actually turns the robot into a closed-loop chain.

Now, since Webots is free too and it actually has a rover model (Sojourner), I'm wondering if it support robots with closed-loop chains.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Webots supports closed-loop kinematic chains thanks to the [SolidReference](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/solidreference) node which allows you to close the loop at any point. Simple example simulations of close-loop chain include the [Stewart platform](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-demos#stewart_platform-wbt) or even simpler, the [pedal racer](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-howto#pedal_racer-wbt). The [NASA Sojourner](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/sojourner) robot is a more complex robot, but doesn't include closed-loop chains.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have one more question, it's about Sojourner robot, which part/point of it is the loop-closure? I may use its model in Webots as a reference for constructing my rover model.

Comment: The Sojourner model does not actually contain any closed-loop. For close-loop refer instead to the other examples mentioned by Olivier Michel.